# SQL Server 2008 - Does a trigger run with the same permissions as the login/user?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, triggers, database-security

Just a quick question:

Say I put an insert trigger on a table in my database.

If data is inserted into that table through a login/user "foobar".

Does the trigger execute with the same access rights / permissions as "foobar"?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

You can control this behaviour with the

```
EXECUTE AS
```

clause of the create statement, as [explained here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx).

The default for triggers is

```
EXECUTE AS CALLER
```

where we find

> CALLER
>
> Specifies the statements inside the module are executed in the context of the 
>   caller of the module. The user executing the module
>   must have appropriate permissions not only on the module itself, but
>   also on any database objects that are referenced by the module.
>   **CALLER is the default for all modules except queues**, and is the same as SQL Server 2005 behavior.

Answer (score 1):

by default yes, but you can change that using

```
WITH EXECUTE AS
```

on the trigger definition

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354(v=sql.100).aspx